Serve static content using nginx from multiple folder
Am trying to host Java document site for all our microservice. We are using nginx to serve the content - We had generated documents for each repo and added them to javadoc folder under the repo.
folder structure
repo 
  javadoc
     - index.html
     - index-all.html
     .....

I tried to render the content directly - it worked
location / {
   root   /path/to/github-repo/javadoc;
   index  index.html index.htm;
}

Now I tried to render multiple repo content - Its not loading the css
location ~ /path2/(?<folder>.*) {
    alias /path/to/$folder/javadoc;
    try_files $uri /index.html =405;
 }


Am expecting below,

Can someone help me in correcting the config, I tried multiple things nothing seems to help.
